# Problem with Image update - autosocial plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I need your light in solving this problem.
I use the autosocial plugin and for 3 days now I've noticed that when I create a new article/product, the post on Facebook is with the company's brand logo and not the image of the article in question.

I would like to know what to do to solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO questions must be about programming, please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'd start by putting one of the article URLs that you are sharing, through the Facebook debug tool, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug, to see if all the OG meta data is set correctly or not. If yes, then this might be a "caching" issue (Facebook scraper hasn't fetched the URL yet, when you first publish, and it simply takes too long); if not, then you might have to look into the plugin settings in more detail.